# Balanced Incomplete Block Design Question.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $v= 58, b = 58$. Show that there exist no design with $2\leq k\leq 56$.

I know $bk = vr$, so $k=r$ since $b=v$.

I also know the other condition, $\lambda(v-1) = k(k-1).$

so $57\lambda = k(k-1)$.

However I don't see how to go about showing why this doesn't hold when $2\leq k\leq 56$. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $\lambda$ is an integer. This gives two possibilities for the pair $(k,\lambda)$. Now apply the Bruck-Ryser-Chowla Theorem.